# How can I access my Windows from Grub again?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, updates

I have been dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 10 for quite a while now and noticed that after the most recent update in Ubuntu, I cannot access my Windows 10 partition from Grub anymore.

I have already reinstalled/repaired Grub and even updated it.

Does anyone have an idea how to go about this

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You may need to reconfigure - 
To boot to Windows, if Windows is installed on first drive/partition, enter in grub command line:

```
insmod chain
insmod ntfs
set root=(hd0,1)
chainloader +1
```

More info: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Chain_002dloading.html#Chain_002dloading for more details.

Comment: Sorry about the very late reply. I tried this method but I wasn't able to access my Windows partition again. I tried reinstalling grub but it seemed like the process sometimes stalled in the middle. I just reinstalled the whole lot but with FDE and I was able to access my Windows partition again.